# Multiplications in a chart, problem solving

Tags: combinatorics

In how many ways can you construct a 6x6 chart with only 1 and -1 such that in every row and column the product is always positive.

Comment: is it mendatory to use both of them...?

Comment: No, you can use only 1 if you like.

Comment: Are reflections and rotations counted as separate ways, or would $$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline -1 & -1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
\hline 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
\hline 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
\hline 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
\hline 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
\hline 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
\hline
\end{array}
$$ 
be considered the same as $$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
\hline 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
\hline 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
\hline 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
\hline 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
\hline 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & -1 & -1\\
\hline
\end{array}
$$ 
?

Comment: @GentlePurpleRain How did you post those images in your comment? Thanks

Comment: @RuchirBaronia They aren't images; they're mathematical "equations" using [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) markup. You should be able to right-click on the grid and view the underlying MathJax code (I'm on my phone right now, so I can't verify). Choose the "Tex" option.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The number of ways is

> $2^{25}$

The idea is that

> you can put whatever you want in the upper left 5 by 5 square, but then there is a unique way to complete this to a valid 6 by 6 square.

This is explained in the below picture:

> [image]